# Tamil Android Application

Tags: android

Is there any framework or design template available to create an Android Tamil static Application ?

If so please share the guidelines. Also which font to use.

Mostly the contents of an application would be the following.
Tamil static content
Hyper links for video
Few Images

Thanks!!

Comment: For problems related to tamil font rendering you can refer to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143484/android-how-to-use-tamil-font). Can you explain more what exact problem are you facing?

Comment: am not facing problems, just am newbie looking to develop an Tamil based Android app. So i need pointers to evolve it.